# TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, express

I am developing a REST API through node using express. When I try to run my application, I get this error:

> ```
> TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
>     at Function.use (/Users/....../Desktop/NodeProjects/MyWebsite/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
>     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/......./Desktop/NodeProjects/MyWebsite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:219:21)
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at EventEmitter.use (/Users/........./Desktop/NodeProjects/MyWebsite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:216:7)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/............./Desktop/NodeProjects/MyWebsite/app.js:32:5)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
> ```

Below is my code:

`app.js` Code

```
  var express        = require('express');
  var http           = require('http');
  var path           = require('path');
  var favicon        = require('serve-favicon');
  var logger         = require('morgan');
  var cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser');
  var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
  var nodemailer     = require('nodemailer');
  var url            = require('url');

  var routes         = require('./routes/index');
  var contacts       = require('./routes/contacts');

  var app            = express();

  // view engine setup
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

  // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
  //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use('/', routes);
  app.use('/contacts', contacts);

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err    = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  });

  app.get('/contacts',function(request, response){
    var get_params = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    if (Object.keys(get_params).length == 0)
    {
      response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
      response.end(JSON.stringify(contacts.list()));
    }
    else
    {
     response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
     stringify(contacts.query_by_arg(get_params.arg, get_params.value));
   }
 }); 


  http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });


  module.exports = app;
```

Code of `Contacts.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');

//Read Json file
function read_json_file() {
   var file = './data/contacts.json';
   return fs.readFileSync(file);
}

//Parse the the file da
exports.list = function() {
   return JSON.parse(read_json_file());
};

exports.query = function(number) {
   var json_result = JSON.parse(read_json_file());
   var result = json_result.result;
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var contact = result[i];
      if (contact.primarycontactnumber === number)    {
         return contact;
      }
   }
   return null;
};

exports.query_by_arg = function(arg, value) {
   var json_result = JSON.parse(read_json_file());
   var result = json_result.result;
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var contact = result[i];
      if (contact[arg] === value) {
         return contact;
      }
   }
   return null;
};

exports.list_groups = function() {
  var json_result = JSON.parse(read_json_file());
  var result       = json_result.result;
  var resultArray  = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   var groups = result[i].groups;
   for (var index = 0; index < groups.length; index++) {
      if (resultArray.indexOf(groups[index]) === -1) {
         resultArray.push(groups[index]);
      }
   }
}
return resultArray;
};

exports.get_members = function(group_name) {
   var json_result = JSON.parse(read_json_file());
   var result = json_result.result;
   var resultArray = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].groups.indexOf(group_name) > -1) {
         resultArray.push(result[i]);
      }
   }
   return resultArray;
};
```

When I comment  out the `app.use('/contacts', contacts);` line in my `app.js` then it works fine. Otherwise I get this issue. I have tried a lot to dig into the reason behind it but have failed. Can any one help me with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), `app.use` is for registering middleware; your *contacts.js* doesn't contain any middleware, it just contains the helper functions you use inside the actual */contacts* route.

As you noted, commenting it out makes everything work just fine. There's no need to do anything else :)

You'll also want to move your 404 handler *after* your routes, otherwise it'll be run before every route, hence the 404s you see. See the [error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks Ruan, actually I am new to node.js. :) . How and where I should include the required middleware to make this work?

Comment: You don't need to, you've `require`d your contacts module and that's enough. No need for that `app.use` call at all.

Comment: This one?   app.use('/contacts', contacts);

Comment: Yes. *contacts.js* is a standard node module that doesn't export any middleware for Express, so no need to `use` it.

Comment: The removal of that line is giving me: "Error: Not Found" for this url http://localhost:3000/contacts

Comment: I wrote my "app.use(function(req, res, next)" function provided in app.js, after  "app.get('/contacts',function(request, response)" and it worked :) . Reason: No Clue :)